# Adding my own code to my own respository in Github error

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to figure out why my own code from my desktop repository is not being pushed into the repository I created in Github.

I did the following:

```
cd "/your/repo/dir"
git clone https://github.com/user_AKA_you/repoName # (creates /your/repo/dir/repoName)
cp "/all/your/existing/code/*" "/your/repo/dir/repoName/"
git add -A
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

and I receive the message:

```
To https://github.com/skumar225/battleship.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/skumar225/battleship.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What is the mistake and how can I fix this?

Comment: You are cloning someone's repo then pushing it up into a bare repo in your account?

Comment: I'm cloning the repo URL from the repository I created in GitHub. Am I not supposed to do that? If that is the case, how do you upload fresh code from a desktop repository to a repository you created in Github?

Comment: Don't clone your own repo. You want to check it out. Give me a minute I can put up an answer you can use.

Comment: I just noticed your second bit about loading into a bare repo. That isn't much different so once you have this sorted I can add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fetch and checkout your github repository not clone it.

If you haven't already told git who you are you should do that now. You can do that per repository or globally. To minimize problems this should match your github information. I prefer to do it globally so I don't have to do it again...

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your.email@example.com"
```

**Setup local repository**

```
# make a directory for your working tree and git repository
mkdir -p ~/projects/{src,git}/battleship
# change directory to the git repository directory
cd ~/projects/git/battleship
# init the git repository (bare)
git --git-dir ~/projects/git/battleship --work-tree ~/projects/src/battleship init
```

**Add remote repository so it can be pulled/pushed to/from**

```
# add your remote (github) repository (upstream)
git remote add github git@github.com:skumar225/battleship.git
```

**Fetch from upstream (github) and checkout**

For this part to work you have to have [an SSH key setup and assigned to ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/). It doesn't have to be setup through github to pull a public repository but will need to be to push to it.

```
# fetch from upstream
git fetch github
# checkout the master branch
git checkout master
# the files are all now in your working tree and ready to play with
```

**Verify your working tree is populated**

```
ll ~/projects/src/my-project
# your local repo is now ready
git status
```

**Make changes to the working tree**

You now have a local repository synced with your repository on github. For the sake of this answer I will add a file and modify a file in our working tree you can commit.

**Note:** This is where the all night, caffeine fueled, coding cram session goes normally.

```
echo '** A new file has been created!' > ~/projects/src/battleship/newfile.md
echo '- [x] Add new file' >> ~/projects/src/battleship/README.md
```

**Staging changes**

Before you can commit the files you must stage them. If you do a status before and after staging you can see the difference.

**NOTE:** You must still be in your git directory to do this without including --git-dir

```
git status
git add .
git status
```

**Commit to local repository**

Finally you can commit to the local repository!

**NOTE:** If you have a longer message omit the -m bit and it will open vim for you to add a longer message.

```
git commit -m "This is a test commit"
```

**Push upstream (github)**

At this point all that is left is pushing it upstream. This part I cannot do since it isn't my repository but it is a simple command:

**Note:** For this part to work you have to [setup your credentials in github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) first so it knows who you are.

```
git push github
```

**A trick to make git easier locally**

I like to setup an alias for each local repository I maintain. This allows me to use git without having to type out the --git-dir each time or changing my directory to the repository.

```
alias gitbs='git --git-dir ~/projects/git/battleship'
```

Now you can just use the alias (from anywhere).

```
gitbs status
gitbs add .
gitbs push github
# etc
```

That is only until your next login though. To make it permanent add the command to your ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Appreciate the details here, especially for a newbie like me.

Comment: If you still need to know how to push to a bare repo on github I can do that too. Really though unless it is an already existing project I usually just let github generate the README and license then pull it.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you've set the remote path (your github repo ssh url) correctly.

Jump into your project folder on terminal

```
$ cd path_to_your_project_folder
```

Check the status of remote info for your repository

```
$ git remote show origin
```

If not set then set it here

```
$ git remote add origin paste_your_github_repo_ssh_url
```

Now time to submit/push your project

```
$ git push -u origin master
```